# Pyspark - Sql filter - Select all rows by checking if the id value is presented in a array

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame in Pyspark which I need to select row where id values is presented in a array. Could anyone help-me, please?

Example:

```
 +---+-----+
 | id| col2|
 +---+-----+
 |123|  2  |
 |245| 32  |
 | 12| 34  |
 |234|  1  |
 +---+-----+
```

array: [123, 12, 234]

Desire result:

```
+---+-----+
| id| col2|
+---+-----+
|123|  2  |
| 12| 34  |
|234|  1  |
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `isin` with `filter`:

```
ids = [123, 12, 234]
df.filter(df.id.isin(ids)).show()
+---+----+
| id|col2|
+---+----+
|123|   2|
| 12|  34|
|234|   1|
+---+----+
```

Comment: It was perfect! Tks!